# Does trait in Scala eliminate the need of adding behaviour through dependency injection?

Tags: scala, design-patterns

We  can include trait with method definition both in objects and at class level.
So Does that eliminate the need of having a reference to an object that implements an interface which we pass as a dependency.

Comment: It depends. In Java Spring one may change dependencies **without recompilation** -- but you may never use this feature. (And by the way nothing stops you from using Spring in Scala.)

Comment: The capabilities of Scala's `trait` can be one ingredient in a statically typed kind of DI. The Cake Pattern is one approach to this. There are others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why, yes. It is known as the "cake pattern", and it can handle things much more complex than you might think. In fact, it supports modularity at a level found in very few other languages.

There are plenty of information about it on the web, but I suggest the excellent presentation by Daniel Spiewak and NEScala 2013, [*Cake Pattern Bakery from The Black Lagoon*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yLbdw06tKPQ), as a starting point.

Comment: Your link was dead. I replaced it with a link to a Youtube video that I believe corresponds to the talk in question.